# How can I build the tutorials from the source distribution of postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to build and then learn from PostgreSQL's tutorials under the [source distribution](https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v10.4/postgresql-10.4.tar.gz)'s `postgresql-10.4/src/tutorial`:

```
$ make
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

So

```
$ sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

But still

```
$ make
Makefile:27: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
```

which is indeed true:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/
adminpack.so           cyrillic_and_mic.so    fuzzystrmatch.so       passwordcheck.so       plpgsql.so             unaccent.so            utf8_and_iso8859.so
amcheck.so             dblink.so              hstore.so              pg_buffercache.so      postgres_fdw.so        utf8_and_ascii.so      utf8_and_johab.so
ascii_and_mic.so       dict_int.so            insert_username.so     pgcrypto.so            refint.so              utf8_and_big5.so       utf8_and_sjis2004.so
auth_delay.so          dict_snowball.so       _int.so                pg_freespacemap.so     seg.so                 utf8_and_cyrillic.so   utf8_and_sjis.so
auto_explain.so        dict_xsyn.so           isn.so                 pgoutput.so            sepgsql.so             utf8_and_euc2004.so    utf8_and_uhc.so
autoinc.so             earthdistance.so       latin2_and_win1250.so  pg_prewarm.so          sslinfo.so             utf8_and_euc_cn.so     utf8_and_win.so
bloom.so               euc2004_sjis2004.so    latin_and_mic.so       pgrowlocks.so          tablefunc.so           utf8_and_euc_jp.so     uuid-ossp.so
btree_gin.so           euc_cn_and_mic.so      libpqwalreceiver.so    pg_stat_statements.so  tcn.so                 utf8_and_euc_kr.so     
btree_gist.so          euc_jp_and_sjis.so     lo.so                  pgstattuple.so         test_decoding.so       utf8_and_euc_tw.so     
chkpass.so             euc_kr_and_mic.so      ltree.so               pg_trgm.so             timetravel.so          utf8_and_gb18030.so    
citext.so              euc_tw_and_big5.so     moddatetime.so         pg_visibility.so       tsm_system_rows.so     utf8_and_gbk.so        
cube.so                file_fdw.so            pageinspect.so         pgxml.so               tsm_system_time.so     utf8_and_iso8859_1.so
```

I was wondering how I can compile the tutorials? Thanks.

Note that:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.4 (Ubuntu 10.4-0ubuntu0.18.04)
```

Comment: `.so` files are already compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension development infrastructure PGXS should be in the *server* development package:

```
apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-10
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does the tutorial need postgresql-server-dev-10 and libpq-dev?

Comment: `complex.c` for example provides a new data type. That is a server extension.

Comment: Thanks. Why does the tutorial need libpq-dev ?

Comment: I don't think that the tutorial needs libpq-dev.